# EmberJs Handlebars Precompile?

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am coding in ember.js have precompiled my `Application.Handlebars` file and it has resulted in a precompiled handlebars template.

Earlier when I was inserting the template in the Index.html page, all I had to do was write :

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="whateverTemplate">
...
</script>
```

However, after I have precompiled my template, and I have included my template js file in the scripts section, I am not able to see the output in the screen. What am I doing wrong? How do you do this?

This is my index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ember CRM Application</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
<style>
    .border{
        border: 2px #666 solid;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
</style>
<body>




<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/md5.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/handlebars-1.1.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/ember-1.4.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/ember-data.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/crm.js"></script>

<!--Templates-->
<script src="js/templates/application.handlebars.js"></script>
<!-- to activate the test runner, add the "?test" query string parameter -->
<script src="tests/runner.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And in the application.handlebars :

```
<h1>This is my template</h1>
```

This is my `crm.js` :

```
App = Ember.Application.create();
```

I don't want to insert a view, I directly want to insert the template. Please guide me.

Comment: try to `create` your application after you have included the precompiled templates i.e. insert `crm.js` after `application.handlebars.js` . Also for debugging purposes make sure the templates are available by running `Ember.keys(Em.TEMPLATES)` in the browser's console.

Comment: @melc : Nope, it is still not working.. I added it after the crm.js but still nothing.

Comment: how about the output on console? please have a look here it has a good explanation regarding precompilation http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/11/07/an-in-depth-introduction-to-ember-js/#what_is_handlebars_template_precompiling

Comment: I think you need to use the handlebars runtime js.

Comment: @AaronStorck : Nope, I dont think that even that would work.. I tried his code.. I too am perplexed. :/

Comment: Have you checked out how the Ember App Kit does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same problem, you see if you use the Handlebars Precompilation, then it would not work. You need to use the Ember-Handlebars-Precompile.

Here is the npm link : https://github.com/gabrielgrant/node-ember-precompile

You can install it using : `npm install -g node-ember-precompile`

After that, you just need to compile it using the Ember Precompiler and it would add anything that is necessary for it to work with Ember. Now you just need to follow the same thing that you are doing. It should work for you.